Read DeltaLake Table through Local Spark SQL registered in AWS Glue
I have orders delta lake table registered on AWS Glue Catalog stored on S3.
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("GlueDeltaLakeExample")
      .master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "hive")
      .config("spark.hadoop.hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory")
      .config("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
      .config("spark.sql.catalog.glue", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()


    val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM example.orders limit 10")

    df.show()
    spark.stop()

I have following env variables configured
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx;
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-3;
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx;

I am trying to run this code in my local machine, but it is not connecting to AWS Glue, instead it is creating local metastore and shows error that table does not exist.

The above code runs on EMR.
To run this in local, you need to build custom spark with patches for spark and hive as explained here. https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-data-catalog-client-for-apache-hive-metastore
After multiple setbacks, I was able to build a custom spark distribution on Ubuntu, which is able to run above code.

I can't see in your sample code where you're loading in the delta table. Assuming it wasn't omitted on purpose, try to load it locally first
spark.read.format("delta").load("s3a://<your-s3-bucket>/<path-to-delta-table>")

